# Edit form ignores validation annotations

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

In a simple user admin implementation (Symfony 4.1.7, easyadmin 1.17.16) the edit form ignores entity validation annotations whereas the new form does not. For example, if an email field in the edit form is empty when the form is submitted an `InvalidArgumentException` is thrown with the message `Expected argument of type "string", "NULL" given`. This exception is also thrown if the validation annotation is removed from the User entity.

The same field when empty in the new form returns the validation message `Email address is required`.

User entity properties (some fields not shown):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"edit", "registration"}, message="Email address is required")
 * @Assert\Email(groups={"edit", "registration"}, message="A valid email address is required")
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"edit", "registration"}, message="First name is required")
 */
private $fname;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"edit", "registration"}, message="Last name is required")
 */
private $sname;
```

easy_admin.yaml (some fields not shown):

```
edit:
    form_options: { validation_groups: ['edit'] }
    fields:
        - {property: 'fname', label: 'First name', type_options: { required: false }}
        - {property: 'sname', label: 'Last name', type_options: { required: false }}
        - {property: 'email', type: 'email', type_options: { required: false }}
new:
    form_options: { validation_groups: ['registration'] }
    fields:
        - {property: 'fname', label: 'First name', type_options: { required: false }}
        - {property: 'sname', label: 'Last name', type_options: { required: false }}
        - {property: 'email', type: 'email', type_options: { required: false }}
```

Comment: Could you try `new:
    form_options: { validation_groups: ['edit'] }
    fields:` and tell if that work

Comment: With the new form using `...{ validation_groups: ['edit'] }` the validation annotations are recognized and the messages appear in the form when empty fields are submitted. This tells me the issue is not the validation group but rather the form.

Comment: It's an argument exception, add `?string` in you setters ;) that mean that your arguments will accept null ,show me your setters please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an argument exception. Try to change your setters argument to accept null argument. This should work and gonna hit the validation callback, for example:

```
public function setEmail(string $email): self
{
    $this->email= $email;

    return $this;
}
```

To this:

```
public function setEmail(?string $email): self
{
    $this->email= $email;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, though, why the difference between edit and new forms? Are they not submitting identical data and using the same setters?

Comment: I think the form component doesn't update fields if they are not changed does not call setter(as when in case of a new object). I will test it local machine and I will update the answer with details

Comment: FWIW if the type hint is not present in the setter the validator annotation is recognized. Perhaps the lesson is that when using validator annotation a strict type hint is not warranted.